# Calculate the sum and display in textbox to total amount and with text "/-+GST" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the amount of the checkbox selected and display the total in textbox and also add prefix "/-+GST" to the total amount.. Amount is getting calculated and how can i add "+GST" text to the amount..

Here is the code

```
<script>
function calcAndShowTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#catlist :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).attr('price')) || 0;
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#catlist :checkbox').change(calcAndShowTotal).change();
```

```
      <div id="catlist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="attending[]" value="Pre-Conference" class="coupon_question" id="attend_1"  price="5000+GST " required /> Pre-Conference 

                <input type="checkbox" name="attending[]" value="Conference" id="attend_3"  price="8000+GST" required /> Conference 
        </div>

 <label class="required-field" for="message"><b>Registration Amount</b><span style="color:red">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="regamt"  id= "total" placeholder="Registration Amount"  style="border-radius:25px;" required>
```

Comment: you could just add $('#total').val(total + '/-+GST'); but i suggest you to not do it. Best way is to add a help text under total . follow this for bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#help-text

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var total = 0;

function calcAndShowTotal(event) {
    let value = parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('price').split("+")[0]) || 0;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      total += value;
    } else {
      total -= value;
    }
  $('#total').val("" + total + "+GST");
};

$('#catlist').click(calcAndShowTotal);
```